# How to make Eclipse action bar items show up reliably?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am adding menu items to an Eclipse action bar.  Much of the time the items show up, but sometimes they do not.  I am using Eclipse Version 2022-03 (4.23.0) on Windows 10.

Here is example code.  In this case, the first item always displays but sometimes the second one does and sometimes not.  I have seen a case where modifying software elsewhere in the app, nothing to do with this action bar or view, changes behavior.

```java
 public void setModelViewMenu(ModelView modelView) {
     this.modelView = modelView;
     if (this.modelView != null) {
         IActionBars actionBars = modelView.getViewSite().getActionBars();
         IMenuManager dropDownMenu = actionBars.getMenuManager();
         dropDownMenu.removeAll();       
         dropDownMenu.add(new FillModelViewPulldown());
         actionBars.updateActionBars();
     }
 }
 
 protected class FillModelViewPulldown extends AllowedContributionItem {
     @Override
     public void fill(Menu menu, int index) {
         if (modelView.getModelViewContent() != null) {
             OntoDescriptor viewDesc = modelView.getModelViewContent().getViewpointDescriptor();     
             MenuItem alertItem = new MenuItem(menu, SWT.DROP_DOWN, index++);
             alertItem.setText("Show alerts");
             alertItem.setToolTipText("List alerts for " + modelView.getPartName() + " in a popup");
             alertItem.addSelectionListener(new ListAlerts());               
             MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem(menu, SWT.DROP_DOWN, index++);
             menuItem.setText("Save viewpoint as...");
             menuItem.setToolTipText("Save viewpoint in a workspace file");
             menuItem.addSelectionListener(new SaveAsViewpoint(modelView, viewDesc));                
         }
     }
 }
```

I expected all the menu items to be shown all the time.  I changed the order of the menu items to make sure the listener didn't matter, and the first item always shows but sometimes not the second one.  I gave specific index values.  I searched this web site and others.

Comment: I can't reproduce this testing with a basic contribution item so it is likely to something in the many classes you haven't shown us. Please make a [mre] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Adding```  PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().activate(modelView); ``` at the end of the setModelViewMenu method seems to make this work reliably.